# Docker image when run drops meinside an interactive shell

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a Django application that I have containerized . It builds successfully. When I run it using the 'docker-compose up', I can access the application svcs' no problem. However, when I use the 'docker run -it -p 8000:8000 'imagename', I get an interactive shell. Why is this happening? My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONWRITEBYCODE=1
WORKDIR /app
# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev 
    
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary

RUN apk add zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
#install pip for the docker image
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY  requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passwd
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile is missing a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 0):

In the compose file you create a command which tell the Django to run.
when you create a `Dockerfile` you use `RUN` for create the image itself and use `CMD` to run command when container create .
also you can run an `entrypoint` which will be run when your container is running .